# Error while loading tidyverse in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

When trying to load the tidyverse package in RStudio, I get the following error message:

> library(tidyverse)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
>    .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
>     call: NULL
>     error: Function getThemeInfo not found in RStudio

Comment: This is a question regarding an error loading a package in RStudio, so it needs the rstudio tag.

Comment: Got the same error. Installing the old Version of tidyverse helped as a work a raound: install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tidyverse/tidyverse_1.1.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

Answer (score 2):

I found that upgrading RStudio to version 1.1.383 resolved the problem for me, while still running the latest version of tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and wolfgang's answer solved it.  I used the following code to install tidyverse version 1.1.1 from 2017-01-27:

```
    require(devtools)
    install_version("tidyverse", version = "1.1.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Thank you..! let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem. Updating RStudio to the latest version (v. 1.1.383) as @bart suggested worked perfectly for me and solved the issue.

For those working in Ubuntu (16.04), you can update RStudio by

```
wget --tries=3 --timeout=120 https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-xenial-1.1.383-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-*-amd64.deb
```

Link to original post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/862403/install-the-lastest-version-of-rstudio