# Issue on loading tidyverse through R Script

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

When trying to load the tidyverse package in R Script, I get the following error message:

```
library(tidyverse)

-- Attaching packages -------------------------------------------------tidyverse 1.2.1 --    
v tibble  1.4.2     v purrr   0.2.5
v tidyr   0.8.1     v stringr 1.3.1    
v tibble  1.4.2     v forcats 0.3.0
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
>    .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
>     call: NULL
>
> error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

However when I try to load it through console the package gets loaded successfully.

Below is the traceback()

```
> traceback()
6: stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
5: value[[3L]](cond)
4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
3: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
2: tryCatch({
       attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
       ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
       env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)
   }, error = function(e) {
       P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
           paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
       else ""
       msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
           sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
       if (logical.return) 
           message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
       else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
   })
1: library(tidyverse)
```

Below is the sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringr_1.3.1        purrr_0.2.5          tidyr_0.8.1          tibble_1.4.2         tidyverse_1.2.1     
 [6] lubridate_1.7.4      zoo_1.8-3            Hmisc_4.1-1          Formula_1.2-3        survival_2.42-3     
[11] lattice_0.20-35      shinyjs_1.0          htmltools_0.3.6      DT_0.4               readr_1.1.1         
[16] leaflet_2.0.1        plotly_4.8.0         ggplot2_3.0.0        shinydashboard_0.7.0 dplyr_0.7.6         
[21] plyr_1.8.4           magrittr_1.5         taRifx_1.0.6.1       rjson_0.2.20         anytime_0.3.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.3.1          jsonlite_1.5        viridisLite_0.3.0   splines_3.5.1       modelr_0.1.2       
 [6] shiny_1.1.0         assertthat_0.2.0    latticeExtra_0.6-28 cellranger_1.1.0    yaml_2.2.0         
[11] pillar_1.2.3        backports_1.1.2     glue_1.2.0          digest_0.6.15       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 
[16] promises_1.0.1      checkmate_1.8.5     rvest_0.3.2         colorspace_1.3-2    httpuv_1.4.4.2     
[21] Matrix_1.2-14       pkgconfig_2.0.1     broom_0.5.0         haven_1.1.2         xtable_1.8-2       
[26] scales_0.5.0        later_0.7.3         htmlTable_1.12      withr_2.1.2         nnet_7.3-12        
[31] lazyeval_0.2.1      cli_1.0.0           crayon_1.3.4        readxl_1.1.0        mime_0.5           
[36] nlme_3.1-137        xml2_1.2.0          forcats_0.3.0       foreign_0.8-70      tools_3.5.1        
[41] data.table_1.11.4   hms_0.4.2           RApiDatetime_0.0.3  munsell_0.5.0       cluster_2.0.7-1    
[46] bindrcpp_0.2.2      compiler_3.5.1      rlang_0.2.2         grid_3.5.1          rstudioapi_0.7     
[51] htmlwidgets_1.2     crosstalk_1.0.0     base64enc_0.1-3     gtable_0.2.0        reshape2_1.4.3     
[56] R6_2.2.2            gridExtra_2.3       knitr_1.20          bindr_0.1.1         stringi_1.1.7      
[61] Rcpp_0.12.17        rpart_4.1-13        acepack_1.4.1       tidyselect_0.2.4
```

Comment: Could you `traceback()` the error?

Comment: I suggest you to start updating R or R Studio, and reinstalling the package.

Comment: I agree with EuGENE try that, otherwise here is a thread that may be useful to you: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/97 - TL;DR:  Install rlang from CRAN again `install.packages("rlang")`

Comment: Can you share your session info and OS?

Comment: @EuGENE updated R and R Studio. However the same error.

Comment: @Johnny  installed rlang again. No effect.

Comment: @csgroen updated the traceback()

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `library` call with require? i.e. `require(tidyverse)`

Comment: @Technophobe01 please find session info updated in the question. I am facing same problem on Windows Desktop R Studio and AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance as well.

Comment: @csgroen call with require worked. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @SnehalKakade So 'require()' works, but 'library()' still does not work? Just checking situation.

Comment: @Technophobe01 yes 'require()' worked and 'library()' didn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while loading tidyverse in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179213/error-while-loading-tidyverse-in-rstudio)